# Why does SDL2 blur pixel art even with SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY set to 0?

Tags: sdl, sdl2

I am working on a game with SDL2 and having trouble turning off linear filtering when upscaling textures.

My game has a bunch of 32x32 tiles. I used [`SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize) so that there is a one-to-one pixel mapping (i.e. my logical size is `n * 32` x `m * 32`.)

However, when the the whole scene is upscaled to fit the actual screen, it seems to be interpolated (blurry).

I saw these two other posts ([1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102870/rescale-pixel-art-scenery-before-rendering-in-sdl2), [2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63156/sdl-zooming-upscaling-without-images-becoming-blurry)) which recommended using `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0");`. I did that, but nothing seems to change at all. It returns `true` and it is in fact changing the hint, but the rendering just doesn't change at all. I even tried setting it with priority but nothing changes.

Any idea how to fix this? I am on Windows if that's relavent.

Comment: Where do you call `SDL_SetHint`?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I tried calling it every frame before drawing anything and also after initialization before starting my loop. It didn't seem to make a difference. Is there a particular place it is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, you need to call it before creating the textures.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 wow, that fixed it perfectly! I was doing it just after creating textures. Weird that I couldn't find that in the documentation anywhere. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0");` needs to happen before texture *creation*.

This is because interpolation mode is a property of created textures, not the rendering pipeline.